# Enum usage in workflow

Tags: c#

I have my entity, named "Person" with a Status field, related to the Status entity; the relation is one-to-one so i have:

```
------------------
Person |  StatusID  
------------------
Mary   |  1  
Mat    |  1  
Billy  |  2  

------------------
ID  |  StatusDescr  
------------------
1   |  Normal  
2   |  Strong  
3   |  Old  
4   |  New
```

I have a workflow that in certain condition the StatusID of the Person table will change from 1 to 2 or from Normal to Strong. I've created an enum, in my code, for the Status table and in my workflow i set the StatusID of person with the correct enum.

The problems i had find is two:
1) If Strong status have a different ID(from Dev to Prod can change) i will setup a wrong StatusID to the target person(if i use ID in searching)
2) If Strong status change name i will setup a wrong StatusID to the target person(if i use StatusDescr in searching)

The first solution i had find is to create another table, to correlate the ID of StatusTable with a field(WF) that represent my workflow.

```
--------------------
StatusID | WF  
--------------------
2        | Strong_WF
```

The second solution is to add a new bit column(IsWF) that represent the possibility to use that status in my workflow.

```
-----------------------------
ID  |   StatusDescr  |  IsWF  
-----------------------------
1   | Normal         | 0  
2   | Strong         | 1  
3   | Old            | 0  
4   | New            | 0
```

There is another solution that i can use?

Comment: Two different enums maybe?

Comment: @Magnus the problem still exists also with two enums because users can also cancel or add new status.

Comment: If they can do that than probably it shouldn't be an enum.

Comment: Yes, i know, but how can i solve?